# Creating a javascript variable from a custom message in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am designing a shiny app that takes a user input, creates a new value from that input on the server side, and then sends that value out to be used in some custom javascript code. It's clear that in order to send messages from shiny to javascript, I need to use the `session$sendCustomMessage()` function alongside the `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler()` method on the javascript side. A sample app might look like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  HTML(

  '<p id="insertion_target"></p>

  <script> 
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("modified_text", function(message_from_r) {
              alert(message_from_r);
            }); 
            var insertion_text = "banana";
            document.getElementById("insertion_target").innerHTML = insertion_text;
  </script>'

  ),

  textInput("text", "Text", "Some_text"),
  actionButton("btn", "Send message")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    modified_text <- paste(input$text, "_modified")
    session$sendCustomMessage("modified_text", modified_text)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So that gets me an alert with my modified text, and a paragraph that can be targeted with a javascript variable. Now I want to save that message to a global variable for use in later script. In this case, replacing 'banana' with the message_from_r in an outside javascript function. I would assume this should work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  HTML(

  '<p id="insertion_target"></p>

  <script> 
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("modified_text", function(message_from_r) {
            alert(message_from_r);  
            var insertion_text = message_from_r
            }); 
            document.getElementById("insertion_target").innerHTML = insertion_text;
  </script>'

  ),

  textInput("text", "Text", "Some_text"),
  actionButton("btn", "Send message")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    modified_text <- paste(input$text, "_modified")
    session$sendCustomMessage("modified_text", modified_text)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or alternatively:

```
   library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  HTML(

  '<p id="insertion_target"></p>

  <script> 
            var insertion_text = Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("modified_text", function(message_from_r) {
            alert(message_from_r);
            return message_from_r;
            }); 
            document.getElementById("insertion_target").innerHTML = insertion_text;
  </script>'

  ),

  textInput("text", "Text", "Some_text"),
  actionButton("btn", "Send message")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    modified_text <- paste(input$text, "_modified")
    session$sendCustomMessage("modified_text", modified_text)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've now stared at this for a while, and concluded that my javascript is poor. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `insertion_text` outside the message handler. In this way, it is a global variable.

And you can trigger a custom event on `body` when the message is sent:

```
<script> 
  var insertion_text = null;
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("modified_text", function(message_from_r) {
    alert(message_from_r);  
    insertion_text = message_from_r;
    $("body").trigger("myCustomEvent");
  }); 
  $("body").on("myCustomEvent", function(){
    document.getElementById("insertion_target").innerHTML = insertion_text;
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is another approach that I tried, but for some reason `insertion_text` is not overwritten during the `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` function call. Even though the alert comes back correct, `insertion_text` is not globally modified.

Comment: @MCWoodruff I see what you mean and I know why, I think. If you move the `if` block inside the message handler? In fact I didn't know why you put it outside, and I was wondering.

Comment: BTW if you move the `if` block inside the message handler you don't need the `if` anymore.

Comment: You're absolutely correct in that I can move the whole `innerHTML` method into the message handler and it will work, but i'm just using that as an example of an 'outside need' of the `insertion_text` variable. For example, I might have another script that requires it as a dynamic input later in the code.

Comment: @MCWoodruff I don't see why you could not control everything from the message handler. Maybe I miss some context. Anyway I've just edited my post, is it better now? I cannot guarantee this is good practice, I'm not a star in Javascript.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, could you please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62651147/10841085)? I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin that requests a remote resource but I'm not sure how to make such requests in Shiny outside of the addCustomMessageHandler and setInputValue functions. Is it possible to make $.ajax calls to the Shiny server?